# What is name of this plant?

Tags: identification

I have this plant in my garden, I am looking for the name of the purple, small leaf plant. I like it very much. It is like creeping plant, but I don't know its name, please does someone know what it is?

**Note:** I am looking for purplish, small leafed plants name.
[image: Click here]

Comment: This usually covers whole pot and it has no flowers. But it looks beautiful when it covers pot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After so much searching I have found out the name of that purplish plant as Callisia repens

It is Callisia [Click here](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callisia_repens)
more info [click here](http://www.gardenseeker.com/indoor-plants/callisia_repens.htm)

This is also called as turtle vine

Answer (score 0):

It has a few names, the most common one being Sorrel.

It's also called Oaxala.

Although this is the classic shamrock shape, shamrock more often refers to true clovers with similar shape.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not looking for that green Sorrel, I am looking for purplish small leafs plant which has spread in the entire pot.I want to know the name of that purplish small plant.

Comment: @user3110224 sorry, I didn't look at the picture close enough. Sorrel also comes purple at the picture resolution I was looking it appeared all the same. Sorry about that. On closer inspection I don't know what the purple stuff is. Looks almost like a tightly noded Jew of some sort.